# jQuery: problem with assigning attributes

Tags: jquery, selector

i'm stuck with an annoying problem - dunno what's wrong here.

my html markup:

```
<div id=myDiv1 widget=bla>test</div>
<div id=myDiv2 widget=bla>test</div>
```

my jquery code:

```
var div = $("#myDiv1");
div.foo = "bar";
alert(div.foo); // returns 'bar'

var div = $("div[widget]"); // grabs both divs
alert(div.eq(0).foo); // returns undefined
```

explaination:
i'm assigning foo = bar to the 1st div,
but when using a selector which grabs both divs and trying to get the already assigned value - i'm getting undefined.

any ideas what's wrong with this?

thanks!

Comment: `alert(div.eq(0).foo); // returns undefined`  Of course it does.  `eq()` returns a filtered jQuery object.  you want to change that to `alert(div.get(0).foo);` to get the actual DOM element.  I assume that is what you intended to do (other issues aside of course).  In none of those examples are you actually doing anything with DOM attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a property on the `jQuery` object, not on the `DOM node` reference.

```
var div = $("#myDiv1");
div[0].foo = "bar"
```

will do it. You also could (and probably should) use jQuerys `.data()` method to store data for a node.

```
div.data('foo', 'bar');  // setter
var foo = div.data('foo'); // getter
```

Reference: [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/), [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `var div = $('#myDiv1')` is a jQuery ***wrapper object*** for an HTML element. The element is unique, but the jQuery wrapper is re-created (thus changes lost) each time you use a selector.

To get around this, you can assign the value to the HTML element itself, using either:

```
div.get(0).foo = 'bar';
// Or
div[0].foo = 'bar;
```

However, modifying the elements themselves, or using non-standard attributes, is not good practice. jQuery provides an alternative mechanism that is safer, `.data()`:

```
// Set data
div.data('foo', 'bar');
// Get it again
div.data('foo');
// Or from your second example
div.eq(0).data('foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
//Adding attribute
$("#myDiv1").attr("foo", "bar");

//Getting attribute 
$("div[widget]:first").attr("foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use attr function to assign attributes.

```
var div = $("#myDiv1"); 
div.attr("foo","bar");
alert(div.attr("foo")); 
div = $("div[widget]"); 
alert(div.eq(0).attr("foo"));
```

Comment: i know this method - but shouldn't it work by directly assigning values to the div object? (i'd like to use it within a plugin).
the only workaround i found is using div.data("foo","bar");

Comment: There are two things assigning a HTML attribute to div element or assigning a property to the div javascript object. FOr the first one you can use div.get(0).setAttribute("foo", "bar") and it will work, for the latter you can't because the value you are assinging to is a different object from what you get when you use $("div[widget]").

Answer (score 0):

you are resetting div, so it doesn't have a .foo value once you do that reset. try this one...

```
<div id=myDiv1  widget=bla1>test</div>
<div id=myDiv2  widget=bla2>test</div>

var div = $("#myDiv1");
div.foo = "bar";
alert(div.foo); // returns 'bar'

var div = $("div[widget]"); // grabs both divs

alert(div.eq(0).attr('widget')); // returns bla1
```